# Can I pass data to a custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to pass data to a custom UITableViewCell but the variables (e.g. studentId) are always null.  Can someone help point out what I'm doing wrong?

**CustomCell.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell { }
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *studentId;
- (id)initWithStudentId:(NSNumber *)newStudentId;
@end
```

**CustomCell.m:**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface CustomCell ()
@end

@implementation CustomCell { }

@synthesize studentId = _studentId;

- (id)initWithStudentId:(NSNumber *)newStudentId {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _studentId = newStudentId;
    }

    return self;
}
```

**StudentTable.m:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSNumber *myStudentId = @5;

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"studentCell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStudentId:myStudentId;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Test the value of  `myStudentId` on you `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. How did you define `myStudentId`?

Comment: I'm setting that in my appDelegate, I've checked and it has a value ready to go.  I've hardcoded myStudentId for demonstration purposes, it still doesn't pass it to my CustomCell init.

Comment: Did you define a table view cell in the storyboard? (e.g. prototype cells in the interface builder, with the reuse identifier studentCell)

Comment: I did not.  I was hoping to do this all programmatically, is that possible?

Comment: In that case you might as well just remove `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"studentCell"]` and place directly allocate and initialize your `CustomCell` with your `initWithStudentId` initializer.

Comment: The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` selector only should be used if you have defined a prototype cell in your tableView. If you haven't done so I think the app will raise an exception, (which isn't the case from what I'm taking. Therefore, you probably have added a cell in the tableView's prototype cells. I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Nate, you are a genius!  I didn't fully understand what dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier did but that makes sense now.  I'm now getting values initializing in my CustomCell. Thank you, you should post that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables aren't being passed over because you are only initializing data when the cell is nil (or for this case, you might have already defined a prototype cell in the storyboard).

To fix this, just do the following *after* of the if statement, `cell == nil`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     Int myStudentId = @5;

     CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"studentCell"];
     if(cell == nil){
         cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStudentId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myStudentId]];
     }


     cell.studentId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myStudentId];


     return cell;
}
```